# VSCode C++ plugin broken when debugging files that have Chinese character in file name

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code, gdb

Moved from [github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/2462) to find a workaround. Details are listed below. Thanks for help.

- OS and Version: Windows 10 1803
- VS Code Version: 1.26.1
- C/C++ Extension Version: 0.18.1
- Other extensions: Clang-Format, Code Runner, and a few themes. Disabled them and the issue persisted
- Bug: When debugging the debugger notice "Can't open file". Chinese characters in the file name become meaningless numbers.
  example:
  "test 测试.cpp" (original) / “test 262342312324.cpp” (after)
- Full error message:

无法打开“test 262342312324.cpp”: 找不到文件(file:///c:/Users/me/Documents/C++ Code/test 262342312324.cpp)。

- Translation: can't open "test ..... .cpp": file not found (.../test .... .cpp)

**To Reproduce**

Steps to reproduce the behavior: (Related files below)

1. Create a file and name it in Chinese, or any other symbols, and add a breakpoint.
2. Hit F5 to start debugging.
3. Error message appears.

**launch.json**

`{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "G++",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "Compile",
            "logging": {
                "engineLogging": true,
                "trace": true,
                "traceResponse": true
            }
        }
    ]
}`

**tasks.json**

`{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Compile",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "-std=c++11",
                "-finput-charset=utf-8",
                "-fexec-charset=gbk"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$gcc",
        },
    ]
}`

Comment: "to find a workaround" --> Rename all the files to only contain ASCII characters. That's one workaround.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the GitHub issue, this is a problem where gdb's MI interpreter is not handling the Chinese characters correctly. The workaround would be, as @jesper_juhl mentioned, to only contain ASCII characters in the path.